# need help to optimize the below query

Tags: oracle

-- pre

```
WITH pims AS
(
SELECT code, value 
  FROM T_QNT_EXT_INFO_TITRES 
 WHERE filter = 'PIMS' 
   AND key = 'INSTRUMENT'
),
generic_param_value as 
(
select value 
  from T_OPS_GENERIC_PARAM 
 where process='PIMSREC' 
   and field in('HBEU_ISSU_INC','HBEU_INV_INC', 
                'HBEU_TRADE_INC', 'HBAP_TRADE_INC')
)

 select t.sicovam, pims.value ,t.devisectt
    from titres t, 
         AUDIT_MVT a, 
         histomvts h, 
         pims     
    WHERE t.sicovam = pims.code 
    and pims.value is not null
    and t.affectation not in (4, 12)
    and t.type not in ('A','F','E','M') 
    and t.sicovam IN (SELECT DISTINCT nvl(h.sicovam, a.sicovam) 
                        FROM AUDIT_MVT a, histomvts h 
                       WHERE  a.refcon=h.refcon(+) 
                         AND a.DATEMODIF >= (SELECT MAX(MARKER_DATE) 
                                               FROM REMOTE_SECURITY.MARKERS 
                                              WHERE MARKER LIKE '%_SOPUS.%'               
                                                AND MARKER_DATE < TO_DATE('&2 10:00','YYYYMMDD HH:MI'))
                             AND a.DATEMODIF < (SELECT NVL(MIN(MARKER_DATE),SYSDATE) FROM REMOTE_SECURITY.MARKERS WHERE MARKER LIKE '%_SOPUS.%' AND MARKER_DATE > TO_DATE('&2 10:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI'))
                             AND EXISTS (select 1 from business_events b where decode(a.version,1,h.type,a.type)=b.id and (b.compta in (0,1) or b.id=15))
                             AND coalesce(a.hsbc_opcvm_upd, 0) <> 1  --mark a trade's modification if it's Drag and Drop 
                             AND decode(a.version,1,h.typesico,a.typesico) NOT IN (4)
                             AND exists (SELECT 1 FROM FOLIO, generic_param_value where ident=decode(a.state, 3, a.opcvm, h.opcvm) START WITH IDENT =generic_param_value.value
                                       CONNECT BY PRIOR IDENT = MGR) 
                      )        
    and not exists (SELECT 1 FROM T_QNT_EXT_INFO_TITRES t2 WHERE t2.CODE  = t.sicovam
                        and t2.filter = 'PIMS' 
                        and t2.KEY = 'TYPE'
                        and t2.VALUE in ('DPT', 'DFD/LBK')
                     )
    and (((pims.value like 'P%')
          and 
          ((t.affectation <>5) 
           OR 
           (t.affectation=5 and (exists(select 1 from histomvts where contrepartie= 10019816 and sicovam=t.sicovam) OR lower(t.libelle) LIKE '%fees linked to p%'))
          )
         )
         OR
         (pims.value not like 'P%')
        );
```

Comment: Would be hard for people to help you because first you need access to test schema, second is I think it is a bad question.

Comment: I tried to format your query a bit.  If you can make the rest of it reasonably readable, that would help.  Tell us what the query plan is.  Tell us what indexes exist.  Tell us how long it takes to run.  Tell us what your goal is.  Tell us how big the tables are.  Tell us which predicates are selective.  Right now, there is no way that anyone can guess what might be slow.

Answer (score 2):

The query is pretty long and syntax is not the best so it is hard to analyse it.

My advice would be:
1. get rid of subquery for `t.sicovam IN` in subquery you're using same tables in main query so you should be able to obtain result with normal where conditions.
2. Second problem is combination of `like` and `or`

If you need more help please rewrite your query to better syntax for joins, post table schemas and describe briefly what would you like to achive.